# The output from SetTimeout function is inconsistent

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create something like a Grid-Image-Box-Slider. Now what I am trying to achieve is that after a period of time (e.g 5 seconds) one of the images will be changed randomly. So, my script follows:

```
var currentImages = [1, 2];

(function imgCarousel() {
    var min = 1;
    var max = 6;
    currentImgSlot = pickImageSlot();
    var pickedImage = pickImage();

    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Image Slot: " + currentImgSlot + "<br> Image: " + pickedImage);
        //var bgImgElem = document.getElementsByClassName('bg1');
        var sheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
        sheet.replaceSync('.bg' + currentImgSlot + ' {background-image: url("assets/img/' + pickedImage + '.jpg") !important}');
        document.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet];
        return imgCarousel();
    }, 5000)
})()

function pickImageSlot() {
    var min = 1;
    var max = 2;
    var generatedImgSlot = generateRandomNumber(max, min);
    if (generatedImgSlot == currentImgSlot) {
        return pickImageSlot();
    }
    return generatedImgSlot;
}

function pickImage() {
    var min = 1;
    var max = 6;
    var generatedImg = generateRandomNumber(max, min);
    if (currentImages[currentImgSlot] == generatedImg) {
        return pickImage();
    }
    currentImages[currentImgSlot] = generatedImg;
    return generatedImg;
}


function generateRandomNumber(max, min) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)
}
```

So, here you can see that inside the `imgCarousel()` function I am using the `setTimeout` to change the background-image randomly after 5 seconds and then calling the same function again recursively. So, according to this code after each five seconds only one image should be changed. But, in reality, sometimes both of the images get changed at the same time. I don't know what is causing this issue.

Any help would be much appreciated. For your convenience I am sharing my code repo here: 
[Git Repo](https://github.com/meghsohor/grid-img-block) 
[Live Demo](https://meghsohor.github.io/grid-img-block/)

Comment: You only ever have one stylesheet active at a time, as such when you change bg1, bg2, the opposite bg2, bg1 defaults to what is in you CSS..  Also note `adoptedStyleSheets` has limited browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to notice, but if you pay attention, in your live demo you'll actually see that **each time they both change, one returns to the default**. This is because you're actually just overriding the `adoptedStyleSheets` property with a new array consisting *only* of the latest override, so your other image will simultaneously return to the primary style sheet's image (the default).

There is no problem with the `setTimeout`, the issue is just that you need to be able to support *both* images being different from the default, instead of exactly one. You already keep both images in `currentImages`, so each time the timeout runs you can iterate over them and set each one's image in the new adopted style sheet.

Naively, something like this might work:

```
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Image Slot: " + currentImgSlot + "<br> Image: " + pickedImage);
        //var bgImgElem = document.getElementsByClassName('bg1');
        var sheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
        for(var i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
            sheet.replaceSync('.bg' + i + ' {background-image: url("assets/img/' + currentImages[i]+ '.jpg") !important}');
        }
        document.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet];
        return imgCarousel();
    }, 5000)
```

Your `currentImages` seems to be used with a random number between 1 and 2, but arrays are 0-based, so I'm not sure what your intended usage is there, but this should get you on the right track.

Comment: I understand that the problem wasn't with the `setTimeout` function. But after adding your code, I can see that only the first image gets changed. Is there any way that I can add/replace css rules to a particular css classname using JavaScript? So, I won't need to use `adoptedStyleSheets` anymore

Comment: if only the first image gets changed, perhaps I misread your random number function, try changing it to `var i = 0` to iterate starting from 0. You could perhaps consider modifying `document.styleSheets` using `insertRule` and `removeRule`. You could also consider using `innerHTML` style overrides or a stylesheet with multiple classes for each possible image and adding/removing classes to your tiles. This would be somewhat out of scope for this question, so I'd recommend doing some research and asking another question if needed. I don't personally work with CSS much.